# Return value from firebase in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use AngularJS for front-end and firebase for database.

I have an `ng-repeat` that displays a `firebasearray` of stories. Each of these stories is connected to a number of collections that they can be a part of. Collections and Stories are stored in two different locations on my firebase server and I use keys to tie these together.

My model for a story object in the database looks something like this:

```
storyId: {
    title: 'title',
    in_collections: {
      0: collectionId //collection id that refers to a specific collection in the database
      1: collectionId
    }
}
```

So whenever I display a story object I don't have access to its title, only its id. In order to get the title I need to call the server for that name.
I currently have this:

Template:

```
<div>
  {{story.title}}
  In collections: 
  <span ng-repeat="(key, collection) in story.in_collections">
    {{getCollectionTitle(key)}}
  <span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("exploreCtrl", function($scope, Stories, Collections){

  $scope.story = Stories.getStory(storyId); //comes as a firebase array

  $scope.getCollectionTitle = function(collectionId){
    Collections.getCollectionTitle(collectionId).then(function(title){
        console.log(title.val());
        return title.val();
    });
  }
});
```

Services:

```
app.factory('Collections', function(){
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('collections');
  return {
    getCollectionTitle: function(collectionId){
      return ref.child(collectionId).child('title').once('value');
    }
  }
})

.factory('Stories', function($firebaseObject){
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('stories');
  return{
    getStory: function(id){
      return $firebaseObject(ref.child(id));
    }
  }
})
```

I can see that it fetches the correct collection title in my `console.log(title.val())` but I just can't find a way to apply it to the view. It is just empty and keeps being that way.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please put your full controller code up

Comment: @gh9 I did now. Also uploaded services in case that clarifies something. Thank you!